# react-admin enable material-ui drawer

Tags: react-admin

All,

I've recently started using [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) to build a small website, and was interested in getting a Drawer from material-ui implemented in the site. I've read the [advanced tutorial](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/08/27/react-admin-tutorials-custom-forms-related-records.html) for adding dialogs and drawers, and even borrowed the `PostQuickPreviewButton` from that article and tried to use in my code, however whenever I add `<PostQuickPreviewButton />` to a view, I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(PostQuickPreviewButton)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(PostQuickPreviewButton) in connect options.
```

I'm relatively new to React and react-admin, but my understanding is that the react-admin framework has a `<Provider>` (and I do see it in my React Developer Tools). It's probably something simple, but just can't see to resolve it. I can post code if needed, but really don't believe I'm doing anything out of the ordinary.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In playing with the tutorial referenced above, I found that updating some of the dependencies (most notably react-redux and redux-form) caused the same error I was encountering with my program. So after some further experimentation, I found the following dependencies worked with `react-admin` :

```
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-admin": "^2.6.2",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-redux": "^5.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.3",
"redux-form": "^7.4.2",
"redux-saga": "^1.0.0"
```

Hope this saves folks some time